# Rewrite Path Variable with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm creating which needs to communicate with some PC software. When PC software call script int needs to include Username and Relative Path to file on server that PHP need to read.

This is PHP in **get.php**:

```
$Username = $_GET['Username'];
$RelativePath = $_GET['Path'];
```

Non rewrited URL looks like this:

> http://localhost/get.php?Username=C8WgtdmAytNhGcq&Path=folder/Test.txt

Now I want to rewrite it to:

> http://localhost/get/C8WgtdmAytNhGcq/folder/Test.txt

But I have problem because Path contains slash.

How I can rewrite it with more than one folder in path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^get/([^/]+)/(.+)$ get.php?Username=$1&Path=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

`.+` will match 1 or more of any character including `/`